# Alternative Proof for Surjections over finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, alternative-proof, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a finite group & defined a one-one map $T$ in $G$ such that $$aT=a^{-1}\cdot aJ$$ where $J$ is an automorphism of $G$ with a property $aJ=a$ only if $a=e$.

I can prove that $T$ is well-defined and one-one. Also given that the group is finite, I can also prove that $T$ is surjective by pigeonhole principle. But, Is there an alternative for the obvious?

(For example, Let $S_x$ be a function of some finite group $U$ i.e $aS_x = xax^{-1}$ for any element $a$ in $U$. I can prove that $S_x$ is a surjection over $G$ by making use of the definition of Surjection i.e by proving that every element of $U$ has a pre-image. And With little calculations we can find that for every element $a$ in $U$ there exists a pre-image $x^{-1}ax$ in $U$ under the map $S_x$.)

Referring the example, can I prove the surjection of $T$ over $G$ without using the pigeonhole principle i.e Given an element of $G$ can I define the pre-image like in the example to prove the surjection of $T$ over $G$?

Thank you

Comment: Is $T$ necessarily surjective of $G$ is infinite? If not, you need to use the fact $G$ is finite somehow. (Also, you're writing functions as acting from the right, but you define $S_x$ to be a left group action?)

Comment: Sorry, Could you please elaborate your statement? Also, Its just my way of writing functions please bear with me. Just treat them like symbols f,g which we usually use to call functions.

Comment: You don't have to use pigeonhole for $S_x$ because $S_x$ is surjective even if $G$ is finite. If $T$ is not necessarily surjective when $G$ is infinite, then your proof that $T$ is surjective when $G$ is finite *must* somehow use the hypothesis that $G$ is finite. And what better way than pigeonhole?

Comment: Ok let me get it straight, I just want to find an expression for pre-image under map T over $G$ just as for $S_x$ we have $x^{-1}ax$ for any element x in $U$. If we can find such an expression then we can convince ourselves of the surjection right?

Comment: That *would* be true, but you will not be able to find such a formula, because $T$ is generally not a surjection if $G$ is infinite. For example of $G=\Bbb Z$ and $J(a)=-a$ then $T(a)=-2a$ is not onto, its image is the proper subgroup $2\Bbb Z$ of even integers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is no.

Consider for example the case where $G$ is infinite cyclic, and $J$ is the automorphism $g \mapsto g^{-1}$. Then $J$ is an automorphism such that $gJ = g$ if and only if $g$ is the identity.

In this case, the map $T$ satisfies $aT = a^{-2}$, so $T$ is injective but not surjective.

Hence there is no formula or expression that you can use to deduce surjectivity of $T$ in the finite case; you will need a different argument. As you mention, in the case where $G$ is finite you can use the pigeonhole principle to conclude that an injective map $G \rightarrow G$ is surjective.

Comment: @testaacount But, Now lets consider a Cyclic group of Order 7 with the same conditions as provided in your example then, From the equation $(a^{j})^{-2}=a^{i}$ for j, we get $2(7-j) =_1 i mod 7$ (The symbol  $=_1$ represents congruence relation) hence for every element $a^{i}$ we shall have pre-image expression $a^{j}$ in compliance with the relation. From your answer I cannot understand how the non-surjection of your example is used to explain there exists no pre-image expression? And also Could you please explain what kind of an argument will I need?

Comment: @Vishalnaakar Yes, in your specific example you do have a simple expression for the pre-image. But the point is that you cannot expect some general expression that works for all groups. The reason is that the result is not true in general, as seen by the example in the answer. You need to somehow use the fact that $G$ is finite.

Comment: @testaacount I guess you have misinterpreted my question, I know surjection cannot be  generalised. My question was, given G is finite and T is one-one its quite obvious that T is surjective. But lets just forget the obvious and go on to find an expression for pre-image under T over G. By that way we can prove the surjection... the result which itself is obvious for we already have an obvious way to prove it...

Comment: @testaacount Considering $aT=a^{-1}.aJ$, Lets just forget the obvious and go on to prove the surjection, Given G is finite and T is one-one we can convince ourselves that there exists a number $r$ such that $T^{r} = E$ where E is an identity map. Following which $$aT^{r} = ((a^{-1}.aJ)T^{r-1})T = a$$. Now we can be convinced that $(a^{-1}.aJ)T^{r-1}$ is the unique pre-image of element a. Thus, T is surjective over G. But, Taken G as infinite we cannot convince ourselves of the existence of a number like $r$, which deems to be pure assumption.

Comment: @Vishalnaakar How do you convince yourself that there exists $r > 0$ such that $T^r = E$, without proving that $T$ is a bijection/invertible? Basically, it seems you are asking for an explicit description to the inverse $S = T^{-1}$, which is equal to $T^{r-1}$. I do not think such a description exists, for the reasons described before. By the way, your equality $aT^{r} = ((a^{-1}.aJ)T^{r-1})T$ does not seem right. The preimage of $a$ is $aT^{r-1}$.

Comment: @testaacount I guess we can prove it, Let me give you an example. Let G be a group of order 8 with P an injection over G. Let us take numbers {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7} as representatives of the elements of G. Using which I propose P as 0-0, 1-2-3-1, 4-5-6-7-4 (the symbol - represents mapping i.e 1-2 is defined as mapping 1 to 2). Following which,
[0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0]
[1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3-1]
[2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2]
[3-1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3]
[4-5-6-7-4-5-6-7-4-5-6-7-4]
[5-6-7-4-5-6-7-4-5-6-7-4-5]
[6-7-4-5-6-7-4-5-6-7-4-5-6]
[7-4-5-6-7-4-5-6-7-4-5-6-7]

Comment: Now, We can find that $r=12$ in this case i.e $P^{12}=E$ by which we can express the pre-image of any element of G. And so I propose that for any case of G given finite and any Injection P over G shall result in existence of a number r>0  and so an expression for the pre-image.